# Как в xampp-е создать несколько папок для сайта?

Tags: xampp

Как в xampp-е создать несколько папок для сайта?

Comment: Очень неточный вопрос. mkdir

Comment: не понятно , что значит несколько папок ? Это вы имеете ввиду для одного и того же сайта ?

Answer (score 1):

Если имеется в виду несколько сайтов, то читайте про Vhosts https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/80431/ http://design-for.net/page/nastrojka-virtualnyh-hostov